# Jenkins / Hudson - Set delay time at build execution

Tags: build, hudson, delay, jenkins

It is possible to set the delay time when executing a jenkins build? 
Like when using p.ex:

http://host/jenkins/job/job_name/build?delay=100sec

But making it with a plugin. I dont know how to get this delay parameter and set it with another value.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think build parameters are stored as environment variables and if that's the case, then you should be able set them using some code like this:

```
build.getEnvironment(listener).put("delay", "250");
```

In your plugin, you would put this in the setUp method of a class that extends the [BuildWrapper](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried it but didnt work, don't find "delay" as a environment variable. Know another possibility to set it? It is possible to get the url that executes job and edit it in the moment of press "build now" button?  Thanks!!!